# Declaring, iterating, searching typelists at compile time

Tags: metaprogramming, nim-lang, typelist

How can we work with the equivalent of boost's `mpl::vector` in nim ?

```
const mytl = [int, float, char]
template t[T](): =
  when T in mytl:
    stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lib that should help: https://github.com/yglukhov/typelists. Feel free to contribute in case you need anything more specific ;)

Comment: that looks very good. next step will be to have a macro to declare variant types from a typelist.